# How to get qt creator ide with qmake version 4.8.4?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

i have downloaded and   installed qt-everwhere-opensource-src-4.8.4 in my pc , i am getting qt4 assistant,qt 4 designer,qt4  settings .But i am not  getting qt4 creator ,how to get qt creator ide with 4.8.4 make version.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator is a separate package; you can get it here:

https://www.qt.io/ide/